# Constructors for a generic subclass pool

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pool & recycle a number of classes, `A`, `B` and `C` which are all subclasses of `Z`. I'd like to have one class that handles all of the pools, such as

```
internal class Pooled {
    Queue<A> AvailableA;
    Queue<B> AvailableB;
    Queue<C> AvailableC;
}
```

I'd like to save myself some redundant typing so ideally we'd put them all in one dictionary. In my mind it would go something like this:

```
internal class Pooled {
    Dictionary<Type, Queue<Z>> dict;
    public T Get<T> () where T : Z {
        Queue<Z> queue = null;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out queue) == false) {
            queue = new Queue<Z>();
            dict[typeof(T)] = queue;
        }
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out var result))
            return (T)result;
            
        // <-- Must construct and return new instance here
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't know if the above approach is alright, but the core of my problem is below.

For the construction code, ideally I could have all `Z` subclasses have a static function `Build()` to generate a new instance. But I don't think I can just call `return T.Build();`

So I thought of making a constructor delegate and then map them to the classes. The `Pooled` class now looks like this:

```
internal class Pooled {
    Dictionary<Type, Queue<Z>> dict = new Dictionary<Type, Queue<Z>>();
    
    delegate Z BuildDelegate();
    Dictionary<Type, BuildDelegate> builders = new Dictionary<Type, BuildDelegate>() {
        {typeof(A), () => new A()},
        {typeof(B), () => new B()},
        {typeof(C), () => new C()}
    };
    
    public T Get<T> () where T : Z {
        Queue<Z> queue = null;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out queue) == false) {
            queue = new Queue<Z>();
            dict[typeof(T)] = queue;
        }
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out var result))
            return (T)result;
            
        return (T)builders[typeof(T)]();
    }
    
    public void Recycle<T>(T obj) where T : Z {
        Queue<Z> queue = null;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out queue) == false) {
            queue = new Queue<Z>();
            dict[typeof(T)] = queue;
        }
        queue.Enqueue(obj);
    }
}
```

Honestly, it felt a little hacky and it probably looks uglier than manually writing a method for each subclass. Typing the constructors in that dictionary seemed to defeat the point of making the pool generic. I also really don't like casting or all the `typeof()` uses.

Is there a better (or cleaner) way to approach this kind of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could solve this by just adjusting the generic constraint :

```
internal class Pool<T> where T : Z, new() { .. }
```

this would enforce using the default ctor for the provided classes. and if you want to expand the support to all classes, you just replace the constraint to

```
where T : class, new()
```

adding `new()` would change your creating from `return (T)builders[typeof(T)]();` to `return new T();` , using this would remove the need of `builders` dictionary along with its delegate.

So, you won't need them, and you won't need to implement `Build()` methods in all classes. You only need to expose their default constructor.

The other note is using `Dictionary` here is not optimal for asynchronous operations. you will need to use one of the thread-safe collections which is under `System.Collections.Concurrent` namesapce. Something like `ConcurrentDictionary` would replace the use of `Dictionary`.

[`ObjectPool<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) is already exists under `Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool` namespace, and I encourage you to use it instead of re-invent the wheel.